# Refreshing div and performing operations with it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Background so far:

A website I'm helping out with uses GoDaddy with Managed WordPress. It seems they cache pages.

We have a Precious Metal plugin that displays a live gold price in the header, but due to caching it stops updating after some arbitrary length of time.

I installed the plugin Ajaxize to see if this would help me get around the problem. I entered the php function name for the gold price and it created an ajaxified div.

Pasted the div into the header field. It displays the price. So far it does not seem to be getting stuck with a cached value. The price only updates when the page is refreshed.

What I need help with:

1. The ajaxified div outputs the gold price per gram. I need it to display in Troy ounces. So the number needs to be multiplied by 31.103 and rounded to two decimals.
2. I would like the div value to auto refresh every 30 seconds. The Ajaxize plugin developer suggested some starting point code in the FAQ, but I'm not a developer... it's beyond my level of tinkering.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: developer's script starting point...

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {

        var $data = $('div[id*="ajaxize_this:REPLACE_THIS"]');
        $data.each( function() {
            $data.fadeOut(2000, function() {
                var newquery = $.query.set('ajaxize_this',
$data.attr('id')).set('_wpnonce', ajaxizeParams._wpnonce);
                $data.load(location.pathname + newquery, function() {
                    $data.fadeIn(2000);
                });
            });
        });

        return false;
    }, 10000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you need to read through some basic tutorials then. You can do something like `$("#myDiv").val( ($("#myDiv").val()*31.103).toFixed(2) )` for updating your div value. Then use `setTimeout( function(){ ... }, 30000)` for updating every 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not a developer yet by any means. It would take me weeks to become familiar enough to cobble something together. I came hoping to find a kind soul willing to help provide a complete solution.  :-)

The Ajaxize plugin developer provides the following code as a starting point for how to refresh every X seconds, but I'm not sure what to do with it. Plus it doesn't have the calculation I want...